# In MongoDB, how do I use $set to update a nested value with a numerical key?

Tags: mongodb

Example:

```
db.parts.update({ }, { $set: { "partNumbers.342": "Wall Box" } })
```

This doesn't seem to work because partNumbers is treated as an array when really it's an object.

Comment: Show how you're inserting your objects please

Comment: Same way, except not all objects have part numbers composed entirely of digits. T2-32 for instance would insert just fine.